# living variable analysis

Tags: math, compiler-construction

I was wondering if anyone could explain me how to work through the liveness analysis?

There are two main equations in use:

```
in[BB] = use[BB] U (out[BB] - def[BB])
out[BB] = U in[s] : for all s ∈ successor[BB]
```

I don't understand the second equation - what is meant when the righ-hand side begins with union? Union with what exactly?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that `out[BB]` is the union of all the `in` sets of its successors. Putting the union operator first is [a common notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28set_theory%29#Notations).